# Graphing a 3D function

Tags: graphing-functions

Is there an easy way of how to graph a 3D function. I tried doing research but none helped. Can anyone show me how to graph a 3D function? Here are the given:
$z=x^2$, $x=0, x=2$ and $y=0, y=4$. Any answer and suggestion will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance for those who coukd help and gove some tips.

It will look like this:

Plot3D[x^2,{x,0,2},{y,0,4}]

But how can I graph it in real life?

Comment: On [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/), use the command `Plot3D[x^2,{x,0,2},{y,0,4}]`

Comment: No no no. What I mean is that how can I graph it in real life not in this website.

Comment: I real life, you could use some clay and shape this parabolic cylinder on top of a wooden rectangle. The surface is like here, but flipped and just a half of it: https://www.mathcurve.com/surfaces/cylindreparabolic/cylindreparabolic.shtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can graph a parabola $z=x^2$, show prismatic lines of extrusion as a cylinder to form a long cylindrical surface along $y-$ direction and out of which truncate the long cylinder so formed between limits ( or cutting plane levels) $ ( y=0, y=4) $ then you are done.

[Wolfram Alpha pic](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot3D%5Bx%5E2,%7Bx,0,2%7D,%7By,0,4%7D%5D)